# Kubernetes Deployment: Error: failed to create deployment:

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Environment Details:

```
Kubernetes version: `v1.20.2`
Master Node: `Bare Metal/Host OS: CentOS 7`
Worker Node: `VM/Host OS: CentOS 7`
```

I have installed & configured the Kubernetes cluster, the Master node on the bare metal server & the worker node on windows server 2012 HyperV VM. Both master and worker nodes have the same Kubernetes version ( v1.20.2) & centos7. Successfully joined worker node to master, below is the get nodes status.

```
$ kubectl get nodes

**NAME             STATUS ROLES               AGE  VERSION

k8s-worker-node1 Ready  <none>              2d2h v1.20.2

master-node      Ready control-plane,master 3d4h v1.20.2**
```

While creating a deployment on the worker node I am getting the below error message.

On worker node, I issued the following command.

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx-depl --image=nginx

Error message is:
error: failed to create deployment: Post “http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments?fieldManager=kubectl-create”: dial tcp: lookup localhost on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

please help me to resolve this issue as I am not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: First of all try to run `kubectl` command from master node but if you still have this problem please answer to my questions: 
Did you modify your `/etc/hosts` file ?
Do you have `localhost` entry in `/etc/hosts` file ?
Can you run command: `ping localhost` from your problematic node ?

Comment: Hi, actually I was executing from the worker node instead of the master node. Yes, I had made the entry in /etc/hosts file. As suggested by user skogul1997 i executed kubectl create deployment on master node and deployment created. BTW thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

May you have to run `minikube start` before. I’m learning and between one class and another I forgot to run this command. I hope I have helped someone.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are issuing the `kubectl create deployment` command on the worker node. This won't work because the kubectl command communicates with the kub-apiserver for cluster communication. Since the apiserver does not run on the worker node executing the command on it will raise an error.

Instead execute the same `kubectl` command on the **master node**  as a **non-root user** with the following additional commands,

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
$ kubectl create deployment nginx-depl --image=nginx
```

Comment: Yes, I was doing that on the worker node. I executed kubectl create deployment on the master node and the pod was created. Thank you very much you solved my issue :)